# I get Error While uploading File Typeerror : Network Request failed, whenever I try to upload a picture to s3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-native, react-native-ios

The code is as follows:

```
 const updatePhotoHandler = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
    }).then((image) => {
      console.log('image', image);
      setImage(image);
      setPhoto(image.path);
    });
    image != '' && uploadImageToAWS(image);
  };

const uploadImageToAWS = async (imageFile) => {
    console.log('upload image to aws', imageFile);
    var files = [imageFile];
    console.log('upload file to aws', files);
    var fileKey = 'some key';

    uploadMultipleFiles(files, fileKey, uploadSuccess, uploadError);
  };

 const uploadMultipleFiles = (files, fileKey, cbSuccess, cbError) => {
  var baseScope = {};
  baseScope.numberOfUploads = files.length;
  baseScope.uploadInfo = {};
  baseScope.afterUploadFileCB = cbSuccess;

  for (var i in files) {
    var file = files[i];

    baseScope.uploadInfo[file.path] = '';
    uploadFile(file, fileKey, handleFileUploadSuccess, cbError, baseScope);
  }
};

const uploadFile = (file, fileKey, cbSuccess, cbError, baseScope) => {
  console.log('fileeee', file);
  console.log('upload filekey', fileKey);
  var mimetype = getMimeType(file.mime);
  console.log('mime', mimetype);
  // console.log("Blob data ",encryptedDataBlob)
  let awsUploadLink = `${ROOT}/get-aws-upload-signature`;
  console.log('aws',awsUploadLink)
  let url = new URL(awsUploadLink);
  let urlParams = {mimetype: mimetype};
  Object.keys(urlParams).forEach((key) =>
    url.searchParams.append(key, urlParams[key]),
  );
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) =>
      awsSignaturePolicyResponse(
        response,
        file,
        fileKey,
        mimetype,
        cbSuccess,
        cbError,
        baseScope,
      ).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error while uploading to s3 ', error);
        if (cbError) {
          cbError('Error while uploading file ' + error);
        }
      }),
    );
};

const awsSignaturePolicyResponse = async (
  response,
  file,
  fileKey,
  mimetype,
  cbSuccess,
  cbError,
  baseScope,
) => {
  if (response['code'] === 200) {
    console.log('file',file)
    let awsSignature = response['content']['s'];
    let awsPolicy = response['content']['p'];

    let dataBlob = new Blob([file], {type: mimetype});
    var uploadPath = fileKey + generateUniqueFileName(file.path);
  

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('policy', awsPolicy);
    formData.append('signature', awsSignature);
    formData.append('acl', 'public-read');
    formData.append('AWSAccessKeyId', AWS_ACCESS_KEY);
    formData.append('key', uploadPath);
    // console.log("Key is ",uploadPath);
    formData.append('Content-Type', mimetype);

    formData.append('file', dataBlob);
    let awsFileUrl = awsS3URL + '/' + uploadPath;

    let uploadUrl = awsS3URL;

    fetch(uploadUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => cbSuccess(file.name, awsFileUrl, baseScope))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error while uploading to s3 ', error);
        if (cbError) {
          cbError('Error while uploading file ' + error);
        }
      });
  }
};
```

Now whenever I try uploading the file.path to s3 I am receiving Network Request Failed.
My image object that I receive when from Image picker is as follows

[image]

Stuck since long now, if anyone could say where have I gone wrong please if anyone could help me I would be very much obliged.
Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @trina have you fixed this issue?

Comment: yes, @a-c-sreedhar-reddy the error was with the blob file, react-native-fetch-blob resolved the issue

Comment: Okay in my case it was the wrong file url.